# Error when searching for a subject having colon

Tags: mailchimp, mandrill

I'm using Mandrill API to search for sent emails.

Everything works nice with this query:

```
{
    "key": "mandrill_api_key",
    "query": "subject:Announcement"
}
```

But this one does not work:

```
{
    "key": "mandrill_api_key",
    "query": "subject:Announcement:Customer has rejected ABC"
}
```

Because the query contains an additional colon. I tried to escape it by adding a `\` or a `\\` before the second one but does not help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

According to [Mandrill documentation](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360039298733-How-to-Search-Outbound-Activity-in-Mandrill):

> A Phrase is a group of words surrounded by double quotes such as "hello dolly".

So, you need to escape the double quotes and send the query as string in double quotes.

```
{
    "key": "mandrill_api_key",
    "query": "subject:\"Announcement:Customer has rejected ABC\""
}
```